# contour integration traversed conterclockwise

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f(z)=(e^z)/z\sin(2z)$
>   calculate the value of the contour integral 
>   [the integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHyos.png)

each og the integrals traversed once counterclockwise

than you

Comment: What is the meaning of your sentence beginning with "each og" ? Is it about some scandinavian hedgehog ? More seriously, show us where you are stuck.

Comment: sorry each of
i dont know hos to find the value of the contour integral

Comment: sorry "each of!